# Bounded Buffer deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I tried to write a simple bounded buffer in Java, but the program seems deadlocked after the first few operations.

```
public BoundedBuffer(int size){
    buffer = new LinkedList<E>();
    this.empty = new Semaphore(size);
    this.full = new Semaphore(0);
    this.mutex = new Semaphore(1);
}

public void produce(E element) throws InterruptedException {
    this.empty.acquire();
    this.mutex.acquire();
    this.buffer.add(element);
    this.mutex.release();
    this.full.release();

}

public E consume() throws InterruptedException{
    this.full.acquire();
    this.mutex.acquire();
    E elem = this.buffer.remove(0);
    this.mutex.release();
    this.full.release();
    return elem;
}
```

Those are my produce and consume methods and they should avoid deadlock. However the program always hangs. Am I missing something?

EDIT: Also added my constructor.

Comment: Did you mean `this.empty.release()` instead of `this.full.release()` in the produce method?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a problem with  `this.empty.acquire()` and never calling `this.empty.release()`. Eventually `empty` will run out of permits.

Comment: The producer releases a `full` permit to indicate that the buffer has at one more item, whereas the consumer releases an `empty` permit to indicate that something has been consumed. `empty` will run out of permits when the buffer is full, and `full` will run out of permits when the buffer is empty.

Comment: @nh0815 In that case, your consume() is not calling `this.empty.release()` when it should.